# Why and how does Object.assign increase app performance in React?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, immutability

I am reading the [Facebook tutorial for React](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html). About 40% of the way through, there's a section called [Why Immutability is Important](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html#why-immutability-is-important) where they state (regarding the importance of immutability):

> The end result is the same but by not mutating (or changing the underlying data) directly we now have an added benefit *that can help us increase component and overall application performance*.

My question is: **why/how?** That is, in React, *specifically* why/how does immutability (using `Object.assign(...)`, etc.) "help increase...overall application performance"?

Comment: The subsection titled **Tracking Changes** seems to explain it quite well IMO - is it unclear, or are you asking for a more technically detailed explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that it is easier to understand with `arrays`:

Imagine that you have an `array`, containing many, many entries.
You replace one entry with another - to see if anything changed `react` has to loop through the whole `array`.

Now, imagine that everytime you make some changes you create new `array` - then the only thing `react` has to do is to compare `references`

`Object.assign` does the same - instead of changing existing `object`, you create a new one, so that `react` can detect changes simply by comparing references